# CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO gives an error

Tags: c#, console

In my C# console application, I'm having an error for this structure:

[image: I'm having an error]

Comment: You need to define the struct; http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ConsoleFunctions.html

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems fairly clear - where were you *expecting* the type to come from? It looks like you're basically missing the declaration of the struct, which you can take from [PInvoke.NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ConsoleFunctions.html).

Basically, P/Invoke is a way of exposing native library calls to managed code, but for complex types, you need a managed representation of the type - and .NET doesn't come with a representation of `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO`, so you have to declare it yourself. `PInvoke.NET` contains a *lot* of these declarations, as well as the declarations for the functions that use them. (They're not *always* accurate, but in my experience they *usually* are.)

Comment: I can't figure out adding the declaration of the struct to my console application.

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok: Um, you copy the code from the web page into your project... where are you having problems?

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok: I have no idea, because I can't tell what you've tried. You find the bit of the web page I pointed you at which starts "public struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO" and copy that struct declaration into your source code. You can keep it as a nested type within Program if you want.

Comment: Finally, I got it working. I was copying wrong. Sorry for my silliness.

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok: No problem - glad you got it in the end :)